# How to correctly pass a function to a prop using a conditional operator in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of book states and a cursor that indicates which book was selected by the user:

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([])
const [cursor, setCursor] = useState();
```

I want to create a new book if the cursor is empty, and change the book if it has been selected. So, I'm trying to pass the desired function through the prop in the following way:

```
<BookModal open={open}
           setOpen={setOpen}
           book={cursor}
           setBook={setCursor}
           function={cursor == null ? editBook : createBook}
/>
```

But all I manage to achieve is the trigger of the create Book function, regardless of whether the cursor is zero or not.

I tried using `===` and `==`, `{cursor ? editBook : createBook}` and `{cursor?.id ? editBook : createBook}`

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: I would avoid naming a prop `function` (for obvious reasons). Call it `action` instead. I would also rename `cursor` to `selectedBook`. Be more clear with naming variables. Also, I think your condition should be: `selectedBook != null ? editBook : createBook`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will change the names of the variables. Unfortunately, changing the condition did not help, I still have the same function, in this case editBook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo for adding or editing books.

- If a book is selected, the action will be "edit"
- If there is no selection, the action will be "add"

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } = React;

const fetchBooks = () => Promise.resolve([
  { isbn: "978-0142437964", title: "In Search of Lost Time", author: "Marcel Proust" },
  { isbn: "978-1840226355", title: "Ulysses", author: "James Joyce" },
  { isbn: "978-0142437230", title: "Don Quixote", author: "Miguel de Cervantes" },
  { isbn: "978-0060883286", title: "One Hundred Years of Solitude", author: "Gabriel Garcia Marquez" },
  { isbn: "978-0743273565", title: "The Great Gatsby", author: "F. Scott Fitzgerald" },
  { isbn: "978-1853260087", title: "Moby Dick", author: "Herman Melville" },
  { isbn: "978-1400079988", title: "War and Peace", author: "Leo Tolstoy" },
  { isbn: "978-0743477123", title: "Hamlet", author: "William Shakespeare" },
  { isbn: "978-0393089059", title: "The Odyssey", author: "Homer" },
  { isbn: "978-0679736363", title: "Madame Bovary", author: "Gustave Flaubert" }
]);

const BookInfo = ({ author, isbn, selected, title, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="BookInfo" onClick={onClick} data-isbn={isbn} data-selected={selected}>
      <span className="BookInfo-title">{title}</span>
      <span className="BookInfo-author">by {author}</span>
      <span className="BookInfo-isbn">[{isbn}]</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const BookList = ({ books, onClick, selectedBook }) => {
  return (
    <div className="BookList">
      {books.map(({ author, isbn, title }) => (
        <BookInfo
          key={isbn}
          author={author}
          isbn={isbn}
          selected={selectedBook && selectedBook.isbn === isbn}
          title={title}
          onClick={onClick}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const BookForm = ({ onSubmit, book }) => {
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState((book ? book.author : null) || '');
  const [isbn, setIsbn] = useState((book ? book.isbn : null) || '');
  const [title, setTitle] = useState((book ? book.title : null) || '');

  return (
    <form className="BookForm" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="book-isbn">ISBN</label>
      <input id="book-isbn" name="isbn" placeholder="Enter an ISBN..."
        value={isbn} onChange={(e) => setIsbn(e.target.value)}
        disabled={book != null} required />
      <label htmlFor="book-title">Title</label>
      <input id="book-title" name="title" placeholder="Enter a title..."
        value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} required />
      <label htmlFor="book-author">Author</label>
      <input id="book-author" name="author" placeholder="Enter an author..."
        value={author} onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)} required />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const BookModal = ({ action, book, open, setBook, setOpen }) => {
  const handleEsc = useCallback(({ key }) => {
    if (key === 'Escape') {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }, [setOpen]);
  
  const backdropClick = useCallback(({ currentTarget, target }) => {
    if (currentTarget === target) {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }, [setOpen]);

  return (
    <div className="BookModal modal" onKeyDown={handleEsc} onClick={backdropClick}>
      <div className="modal-panel">
        <div className="modal-panel-title">
          {book ? 'Edit Book' : 'Create Book'}
        </div>
        <div className="modal-panel-content">
          <BookForm book={book} onSubmit={action} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const findBook = (books, book) => book && books
  ? books.find(currBook => currBook.isbn === book.isbn)
  : null;

const formToBook = (form) => ({
  isbn: form.elements.isbn.value.trim(),
  title: form.elements.title.value.trim(),
  author: form.elements.author.value.trim() 
})

const App = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([])
  const [selectedBook, setSelectedBook] = useState(null);
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);

  const editBook = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const updatedBook = formToBook(e.target);
    setBooks((currBooks) => {
      const copyBooks = structuredClone(currBooks);
      const book = findBook(copyBooks, updatedBook);
      Object.assign(book, updatedBook); // Update the book
      return copyBooks;
    });
    setSelectedBook(updatedBook);
    setModalOpen(false);
  }, []);
  
  const createBook = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newBook = formToBook(e.target);
    setBooks((currBooks) => {
      const copyBooks = structuredClone(currBooks);
      copyBooks.push(newBook); // Add the book
      return copyBooks;
    });
    setModalOpen(false);
  }, []);
  
  const deleteBook = useCallback((e) => {
    setBooks((currBooks) => {
      const copyBooks = structuredClone(currBooks);
      const index = copyBooks.findIndex(b => b.isbn === selectedBook.isbn);
      if (index !== -1) {
        copyBooks.splice(index, 1); // Remove the book
      }
      return copyBooks;
    });
    setSelectedBook(null);
  }, [selectedBook]);
  
  const toggleSelected = useCallback((e) => {
    const bookInfo = e.currentTarget;
    const { isbn } = bookInfo.dataset;
    const book = findBook(books, { isbn });
    setSelectedBook((prevBook) => {
      if (prevBook && prevBook.isbn === isbn) {
        return null;
      }
      return book;
    });
  }, [books]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBooks().then(setBooks);
  }, []);

  const buttonText = useMemo(() =>
    selectedBook != null ? 'Edit Book' : 'Add Book', [selectedBook]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Books</h2>
      <div className="actions">
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>{buttonText}</button>
        {selectedBook != null &&
          <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteBook()}>Delete Book</button>}
        </div>
      <BookList
        books={books}
        selectedBook={selectedBook}
        onClick={toggleSelected} />
      {modalOpen &&
        <BookModal
          action={selectedBook != null ? editBook : createBook}
          book={selectedBook}
          open={modalOpen}
          onClose={setModalOpen}
          setBook={setSelectedBook}
          setOpen={setModalOpen}
      />}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%:
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #FFF;
  border: thin solid grey;
}

.modal-panel-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.modal-panel-content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.BookList {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.125rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.BookInfo {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.BookInfo:hover {
  background: #FFD;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.BookInfo[data-selected="true"] {
  background: #FF7;
}

.BookInfo-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.BookInfo-author {
  font-style: italic;
}

.BookInfo-isbn {
  color: #555;
}

.BookForm {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.BookForm button[type="submit"] {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.actions {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

**Note:** Since stack snippets use an older version of Babel, I had to do this:

```js
// Ternary + Logical OR (older; verbose)
const [author, setAuthor] = useState((book ? book.author : null) || '');
```

Instead of the more standard:

```js
// Optional Chaining + Nullish-Coalescing (modern; simpler)
const [author, setAuthor] = useState(book?.author ?? '');
```